# Connection refused

Tags: amazon-ec2, linux-networking

My AWS Linux AMI EC2 instance runs fine for a few days but then https, ssh and vsftp connections are all refused. Pings still work. If I stop/start the instance it runs again for a few days until the problem repeats again.
What should I check on the instance while I can still access it?
Any ideas why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: A possible source is growing memory and/or swap usage. Presumably you have an application running. You can also monitor this through Cloudwatch.

Comment: Also check /var/log/syslog for any errors after a reboot.  It sounds to me like there is a process or processes that are running the machine out of resources, memory, file descriptors, etc.  Re-booting resets this condition.  Cloudwatch is a good call too, it will show you the instances resources and you can check to see if usage of a particular resource is growing.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Great ideas. I will check Cloudwatch and/or add some extra metrics.

Comment: I noticed this "cannot allocate memory" in the messages log.

Dec 31 10:50:12 ip-10-1-1-99 dhclient[2251]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 114080ms.
Dec 31 10:52:11 ip-10-1-1-99 dhclient[2251]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 120780ms.
Dec 31 10:52:53 ip-10-1-1-99 dhclient[2129]: fork: Cannot allocate memory

Comment: Cloudwatch "mem used %" metric is at 88% when these messages start.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed.
I changed the instance type from T2.micro to T2.small. The memory usage is now stable at around 40% and the instance has been running for several days without losing access.